# How to use PaperTrail versioning with has_many :through to Reify associations in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through, paper-trail-gem

Trying to use PaperTrail for versioning
My associations aren't reverting. I must be doing something wrong. 
Here's a similar setup to mine. I'm using the latest master branch of PaperTrail.

```
class Ball < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ball_colors
  has_many :colors, through: :ball_colors
  has_paper_trail
end

class BallColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ball 
  belongs_to :color
  has_paper_trail
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :ball_colors
  has_many :balls, through: :ball_colors
end
```

This is what I'm doing.

```
ball = Ball.create()
ball.name = 'Before I add color'
ball.save

ball.colors << Color.create(name: 'blue')
ball.save #although this is unnecessary i think 

ball.name = 'After adding color'
ball.save

b = ball.versions.last.reify(:has_many => true)
b.save

b.reload
b.name  #=> 'Before I add color'
b.colors #=> [Blue]
```

b.colors should be empty.
Also, ball.versions doesn't include the change when I added a color to the ball. There's only create, update for 'Before I add color', update for 'After adding color'.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me to an example? 
I've read the Associations section of the documentation but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the docs correctly it means that paper trail is able to restore associations.

See the project [github](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#associations) page associations chapter.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ball.versions.last.reify(:has_many => true).save!`. `reify` just shows you the previous version I think.

Comment: I can't comment on other people's stuff but on another note if anybody knows how to reify has_many with `validates :models, length: { minimum: 1 }` that'd be great. The record restores correctly with the association without the validation, but with the validation, it will not save complaining of validation failure.